# Install virtualenv for python2.7 on debian 10

Tags: debian, python, pip, virtualenv

I want to use `python2.7` with `virtualenv`. I recently upgraded from debian 8 to debian 10. I originally had `python2.7` and `pip` installed on debian 8, but maybe something happened during the installation and now I don't have `pip`. But I do still have `python2.7` installed:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.16
```

So I just installed `pip` like so:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
$ python get-pip.py
```

And now I can see that I have pip installed:

```
$ which pip
/home/me/.local/bin/pip
$ pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

**Firstly, is this where pip should be installed?** Under my home directory? I am the only user on this PC, but I'm not sure if `pip` should be in `/usr/share/` or somewhere more public for it to work properly? Should I have used `sudo python /tmp/get-pip.py` to install `pip`? I don't plan to run python as root, but `apt` always requires root for installations, so maybe installing `pip` should have too? The documentation did not specify.

Anyway, next I tried to update `pip` to the latest version and install `virtualenv`:

```
$ pip install -U pip
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (20.0.2)

$ pip install virtualenv
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (15.1.0)
```

All seems good. But when I try and check which version of `virtualenv` I have, it fails:

```
$ virtualenv --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 6, in <module>
    from virtualenv.__main__ import run_with_catch
ImportError: No module named __main__
```

And if I try and use `virtualenv` it always throws up these errors.

So overall, my question is to how correctly install `python2.7`, `pip` and `virtualenv` on debian 10. I don't mind uninstalling everything and starting again if that is what it takes.

---

As instructed by [Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt) in the answer below, I have tried uninstalling the versions of `pip` and `virtualenv` that I previously installed with `get-pip.py`, however this gives some new errors. I will explain exactly what I have done...

First uninstall `virtualenv`:

```
$ pip uninstall virtualenv
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Found existing installation: virtualenv 15.1.0
Uninstalling virtualenv-15.1.0:
  Would remove:
    /home/me/.local/bin/virtualenv
    /home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0.dist-info/*
    /home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py
    /home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled virtualenv-15.1.0
```

Seems fine. Then uninstall pip:

```
$ python -m pip uninstall pip
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Found existing installation: pip 20.0.2
Uninstalling pip-20.0.2:
  Would remove:
    /home/me/.local/bin/pip
    /home/me/.local/bin/pip2
    /home/me/.local/bin/pip2.7
    /home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-20.0.2.dist-info/*
    /home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled pip-20.0.2

$ pip --version
bash: /home/me/.local/bin/pip: No such file or directory
$ ls -a ~/.local/bin
.  ..  chardetect  easy_install  easy_install-2.7  flake8  pew  pipenv  pycodestyle  pyflakes  virtualenv-clone
```

That also seems fine. I'm not sure how bash knows that `pip` should be `/home/me/.local/bin/pip` since that file does not exist. Maybe bash has a cache? Anyway, next install `pip` and `virtualenv` from the debian 10 repo:

```
$ sudo apt install python-pip virtualenv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-distutils python3-lib2to3 python3-virtualenv
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-pip python3-distutils python3-lib2to3 python3-virtualenv virtualenv
```

But when I try and check what version of `virtualenv` I now have, it fails:

```
$ virtualenv --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 6, in <module>
    from virtualenv.__main__ import run_with_catch
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .run import cli_run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv/run/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from virtualenv.run.app_data import AppDataAction
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv/run/app_data.py", line 8, in <module>
    from virtualenv.util.lock import ReentrantFileLock
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv/util/lock.py", line 11, in <module>
    from virtualenv.util.path import Path
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv/util/path/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ._pathlib import Path
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv/util/path/_pathlib/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pathlib2 import Path
ImportError: No module named pathlib2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid messing things up *outside* the virtualenvs, I recommend using the packaged versions:

```
sudo apt install python-pip virtualenv
```

(along with `python3-pip` for Python 3 support, if appropriate).

You’ll probably need to remove the versions of `pip` and `virtualenv` installed in your home directory, and any others on your `PATH` outside `/usr/bin`.

When setting up your virtualenvs, you can specify Python 2.7:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 ...
```

and `virtualenv` will do the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

Upon further investigation and discussion with [Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt) I found that I had 2 different versions of `virtualenv` on my PC:

```
$ find /usr/ -iname "virtualenv" | grep bin
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
/usr/bin/virtualenv
```

The one in `/usr/bin/virtualenv` does not throw errors when I run it:

```
$ /usr/bin/virtualenv --version
15.1.0
```

And doing some web searches I found that the one in `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv` must have been installed with `pip` as root. So I uninstalled it with `pip` as root:

```
$ sudo pip uninstall virtualenv
Uninstalling virtualenv-20.0.13:
  Would remove:
    /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-20.0.13.dist-info/*
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv/*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled virtualenv-20.0.13
```

Now all is well:

```
$ which virtualenv
/usr/bin/virtualenv
$ find /usr/ -iname "virtualenv" | grep bin
/usr/bin/virtualenv
```