# Why is a non-standard Python installation so heavy?

Tags: debian, apt, python3

Let's say I have a Debian 10 VPS server, which does not have a lot of storage (20 GB). I use this server for various things, such as web server, automation platform, and such.

For some reasons, I'd want to install a specific version of Python, let's say the 3.6. However, when I try to run an `apt install python3.6`, here is the huge output that the command provides me:

```
root@labdebian10:~ # apt install python3.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python3.6-kdtree-dbg' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-cups' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-ldap' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-cairo' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-sfml' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-pymad-dbg' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-nss' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-pypcap' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-2to3' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-urwid' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-silo' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-gevent-dbg' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-prelude' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-smbus' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-btrees' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-radix' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-subvertpy' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-smbc' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'libpython3.6-stdlib' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-ldap-dbg' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-indexed-gzip' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-grpcio' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-yenc' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-crypto' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-tango' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-gevent' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-kdtree' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-casacore' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-pyodbc' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-blist' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-jpype' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-pyxattr-dbg' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-pymad' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-newt' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-pyisomd5sum' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-zodbpickle' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-rpy2' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-pyraf' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-crypto-dbg' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-pyalsa' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-bluez' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-pyaudio' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-icu-dbg' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-http-parser' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-selinux' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-kyotocabinet' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-wheezy.template' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-qrencode' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-deltarpm' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-zope.interface' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-pyxattr' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-gssapi' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-sendfile-dbg' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-ftdi1' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-cairo-dbg' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-hid' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-sane' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-icu' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-jpy' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3-blist' instead of 'python3.6-blist'
Note, selecting 'python3-deltarpm' instead of 'python3.6-deltarpm'
Note, selecting 'python3-grpcio' instead of 'python3.6-grpcio'
Note, selecting 'python3-smbus' instead of 'python3.6-smbus'
Note, selecting 'python3-indexed-gzip' instead of 'python3.6-indexed-gzip'
Note, selecting 'python3-pyisomd5sum' instead of 'python3.6-pyisomd5sum'
Note, selecting 'python3-jpy' instead of 'python3.6-jpy'
Note, selecting 'python3-ftdi1' instead of 'python3.6-ftdi1'
Note, selecting 'python3-kdtree' instead of 'python3.6-kdtree'
Note, selecting 'python3-kdtree-dbg' instead of 'python3.6-kdtree-dbg'
Note, selecting 'python3-prelude' instead of 'python3.6-prelude'
Note, selecting 'python3-selinux' instead of 'python3.6-selinux'
Note, selecting 'python3-newt' instead of 'python3.6-newt'
Note, selecting 'python3-sane' instead of 'python3.6-sane'
Note, selecting 'python3-radix' instead of 'python3.6-radix'
Note, selecting 'python3-bluez' instead of 'python3.6-bluez'
Note, selecting 'python3-cairo' instead of 'python3.6-cairo'
Note, selecting 'python3-cairo-dbg' instead of 'python3.6-cairo-dbg'
Note, selecting 'python3-icu' instead of 'python3.6-icu'
Note, selecting 'python3-icu-dbg' instead of 'python3.6-icu-dbg'
Note, selecting 'python3-pymad' instead of 'python3.6-pymad'
Note, selecting 'python3-pymad-dbg' instead of 'python3.6-pymad-dbg'
Note, selecting 'python3-pyodbc' instead of 'python3.6-pyodbc'
Note, selecting 'python3-pyraf' instead of 'python3.6-pyraf'
Note, selecting 'python3-sendfile-dbg' instead of 'python3.6-sendfile-dbg'
Note, selecting 'python3-smbc' instead of 'python3.6-smbc'
Note, selecting 'python3-tango' instead of 'python3.6-tango'
Note, selecting 'python3-btrees' instead of 'python3.6-btrees'
Note, selecting 'python3-casacore' instead of 'python3.6-casacore'
Note, selecting 'python3-crypto' instead of 'python3.6-crypto'
Note, selecting 'python3-crypto-dbg' instead of 'python3.6-crypto-dbg'
Note, selecting 'python3-cups' instead of 'python3.6-cups'
Note, selecting 'python3-gevent' instead of 'python3.6-gevent'
Note, selecting 'python3-gevent-dbg' instead of 'python3.6-gevent-dbg'
Note, selecting 'python3-gssapi' instead of 'python3.6-gssapi'
Note, selecting 'python3-hid' instead of 'python3.6-hid'
Note, selecting 'python3-http-parser' instead of 'python3.6-http-parser'
Note, selecting 'python3-jpype' instead of 'python3.6-jpype'
Note, selecting 'python3-kyotocabinet' instead of 'python3.6-kyotocabinet'
Note, selecting 'python3-ldap' instead of 'python3.6-ldap'
Note, selecting 'python3-ldap-dbg' instead of 'python3.6-ldap-dbg'
Note, selecting 'python3-nss' instead of 'python3.6-nss'
Note, selecting 'python3-pyalsa' instead of 'python3.6-pyalsa'
Note, selecting 'python3-pyaudio' instead of 'python3.6-pyaudio'
Note, selecting 'python3-pypcap' instead of 'python3.6-pypcap'
Note, selecting 'python3-pyxattr' instead of 'python3.6-pyxattr'
Note, selecting 'python3-pyxattr-dbg' instead of 'python3.6-pyxattr-dbg'
Note, selecting 'python3-qrencode' instead of 'python3.6-qrencode'
Note, selecting 'python3-sfml' instead of 'python3.6-sfml'
Note, selecting 'python3-wheezy.template' instead of 'python3.6-wheezy.template'
Note, selecting 'python3-yenc' instead of 'python3.6-yenc'
Note, selecting 'python3-rpy2' instead of 'python3.6-rpy2'
Note, selecting 'python3-silo' instead of 'python3.6-silo'
Note, selecting 'python3-subvertpy' instead of 'python3.6-subvertpy'
Note, selecting 'python3-urwid' instead of 'python3.6-urwid'
Note, selecting 'python3-zodbpickle' instead of 'python3.6-zodbpickle'
Note, selecting 'python3-zope.interface' instead of 'python3.6-zope.interface'
python3-zope.interface is already the newest version (4.3.2-1+b2).
python3-zope.interface set to manually installed.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  acl adwaita-icon-theme at-spi2-core autoconf automake autotools-dev binutils binutils-common
  binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu blt build-essential bzip2 bzip2-doc ca-certificates-java casacore-data casacore-data-igrf
  casacore-data-jpl-de200 casacore-data-jpl-de405 casacore-data-lines casacore-data-observatories
  casacore-data-sources casacore-data-tai-utc cpp cpp-8 cython3 dbus-user-session dconf-gsettings-backend
  dconf-service default-jre default-jre-headless dh-python dpkg-dev fakeroot fontconfig fontconfig-config
  fonts-dejavu-core fonts-dejavu-extra g++ g++-8 gcc gcc-8 gdb gfortran gfortran-8 glib-networking
  glib-networking-common glib-networking-services gsettings-desktop-schemas gtk-update-icon-cache hicolor-icon-theme
  i2c-tools ibverbs-providers icu-devtools iraf iraf-noao java-common javascript-common libaec0 libalgorithm-diff-perl
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libapr1 libaprutil1 libasan5 libasound2 libasound2-data
  libasyncns0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatomic1
  libatspi2.0-0 libauthen-sasl-perl libbabeltrace1 libbinutils libblas-dev libblas3 libbluetooth3
  libboost-python1.67.0 libbz2-1.0 libbz2-dev libc-ares2 libc-dev-bin libc6-dbg libc6-dev libcaf-openmpi-3
  libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2 libcasa-casa3 libcasa-coordinates3 libcasa-fits3 libcasa-images3 libcasa-lattices3
  libcasa-measures3 libcasa-mirlib3 libcasa-ms3 libcasa-python3-3 libcasa-scimath-f3 libcasa-scimath3 libcasa-tables3
  libcc1-0 libcfitsio7 libcminpack1 libcoarrays-dev libcoarrays-openmpi-dev libcolord2 libcos4-2 libcroco3 libcups2
  libdata-dump-perl libdatrie1 libdconf1 libdpkg-perl libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-common libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2
  libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libdw1 libencode-locale-perl libepoxy0 liberfa1 libevent-2.1-6 libevent-core-2.1-6
  libevent-pthreads-2.1-6 libexif12 libexpat1 libexpat1-dev libfabric1 libfakeroot libfftw3-double3 libfftw3-single3
  libfile-basedir-perl libfile-desktopentry-perl libfile-fcntllock-perl libfile-listing-perl libfile-mimeinfo-perl
  libflac8 libfont-afm-perl libfontconfig1 libfontenc1 libfribidi0 libftdi1-2 libfuntools1 libgail-common libgail18
  libgcc-8-dev libgd3 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgfortran-8-dev libgfortran5
  libgif7 libgl1 libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libglvnd0 libglx-mesa0 libglx0 libgphoto2-6 libgphoto2-l10n
  libgphoto2-port12 libgraphite2-3 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common
  libharfbuzz0b libhdf5-openmpi-103 libhidapi-hidraw0 libhidapi-libusb0 libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl
  libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl
  libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libhwloc-dev libhwloc-plugins libhwloc5 libi2c0 libibverbs-dev
  libibverbs1 libice6 libicu-dev libicu63 libieee1284-3 libimagequant0 libio-html-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl
  libio-stringy-perl libipc-system-simple-perl libipt2 libisl19 libitm1 libjack-jackd2-0 libjansson4 libjbig0
  libjpeg-dev libjpeg62-turbo libjpeg62-turbo-dev libjs-jquery libjs-jquery-datatables libjson-glib-1.0-0
  libjson-glib-1.0-common libkyotocabinet16v5 liblapack-dev liblapack3 liblcms2-2 libldb1 libllvm7 liblog4tango5v5
  liblsan0 libltdl-dev libltdl7 liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl liblzma-dev liblzo2-2 libmad0
  libmailtools-perl libmariadb3 libmpc3 libmpfr6 libmpx2 libncurses-dev libncurses5-dev libncurses6 libncursesw6
  libnet-dbus-perl libnet-http-perl libnet-smtp-ssl-perl libnl-3-200 libnl-3-dev libnl-route-3-200 libnl-route-3-dev
  libnorm1 libnspr4 libnss3 libnuma-dev libnuma1 libodbc1 libogg0 libomniorb4-2 libomnithread4 libopenal-data
  libopenal1 libopenmpi-dev libopenmpi3 libopus0 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpaper-utils
  libpaper1 libpcap0.8 libpciaccess0 libpcre16-3 libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libpcsclite1 libpgm-5.2-0
  libpixman-1-0 libpmix2 libpng-dev libpng-tools libportaudio2 libprelude23 libpreludecpp8 libproxy1v5
  libpsm-infinipath1 libpsm2-2 libpulse0 libpython3-dbg libpython3-dev libpython3.7 libpython3.7-dbg libpython3.7-dev
  libpython3.7-minimal libpython3.7-stdlib libqrencode4 libquadmath0 librdmacm1 libreadline-dev librest-0.7-0
  librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsamplerate0 libsane libsane-common libsensors-config libsensors5 libserf-1-1
  libsfml-audio2.5 libsfml-graphics2.5 libsfml-network2.5 libsfml-system2.5 libsfml-window2.5 libsigsegv2 libsiloh5-0
  libsm6 libsmbclient libsndfile1 libsndio7.0 libsnmp-base libsnmp30 libsodium23 libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1
  libstarlink-ast-err0 libstarlink-ast0 libstarlink-pal0 libstdc++-8-dev libsvn1 libsz2 libtalloc2 libtango9 libtcl8.6
  libtdb1 libtevent0 libthai-data libthai0 libtie-ixhash-perl libtiff5 libtimedate-perl libtinfo6 libtk-img libtk8.6
  libtool libtry-tiny-perl libtsan0 libubsan1 liburi-perl libutempter0 libutf8proc2 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2
  libvorbisfile3 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1 libwbclient0 libwcs6 libwcstools1 libwebp6
  libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux3 libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libx11-protocol-perl libx11-xcb1 libx86-1 libxaw7
  libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-sync1
  libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxft2 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxml-parser-perl
  libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpathengine-perl libxmu6 libxpa1 libxpm4 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxshmfence1 libxslt1.1
  libxss1 libxt6 libxtst6 libxv1 libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1 libzmq5 linux-libc-dev m4 make manpages-dev mariadb-common
  mysql-common ocl-icd-libopencl1 openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jre-headless openmpi-bin openmpi-common patch pkg-config
  prelude-utils python-talloc python3-astropy python3-atomicwrites python3-attr python3-dbg python3-decorator
  python3-dev python3-greenlet python3-greenlet-dbg python3-ipython python3-ipython-genutils python3-jinja2
  python3-markupsafe python3-more-itertools python3-numpy python3-olefile python3-persistent python3-pexpect
  python3-pickleshare python3-pil python3-pluggy python3-ply python3-prompt-toolkit python3-psutil python3-ptyprocess
  python3-py python3-pyasn1 python3-pyasn1-modules python3-pygments python3-pytest python3-pytest-arraydiff
  python3-pytest-astropy python3-pytest-doctestplus python3-pytest-openfiles python3-pytest-remotedata python3-scipy
  python3-sendfile python3-simplegeneric python3-stsci.tools python3-tk python3-traitlets python3-wcwidth python3.7
  python3.7-dbg python3.7-dev python3.7-minimal r-base-core r-base-dev r-cran-boot r-cran-class r-cran-cluster
  r-cran-codetools r-cran-foreign r-cran-kernsmooth r-cran-lattice r-cran-mass r-cran-matrix r-cran-mgcv r-cran-nlme
  r-cran-nnet r-cran-rpart r-cran-spatial r-cran-survival r-doc-html r-recommended read-edid samba-libs sane-utils
  saods9 saods9-doc tango-common tcl tcl-signal tcl-tls tcl-xpa tcl8.6 tcliis tcllib tclxml tk tk-html1 tk-mpeg
  tk-table tk8.6 tk8.6-blt2.5 tkblt tkcon tksao unzip update-inetd x11-common x11-utils x11-xserver-utils xbitmaps
  xdg-utils xterm zip zlib1g-dev
Suggested packages:
  autoconf-archive gnu-standards autoconf-doc gettext binutils-doc blt-demo casacore-data-eop casacore-data-predict
  cpp-doc gcc-8-locales cython-doc debian-keyring g++-multilib g++-8-multilib gcc-8-doc libstdc++6-8-dbg gcc-multilib
  flex bison gcc-doc gcc-8-multilib libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan5-dbg liblsan0-dbg
  libtsan0-dbg libubsan1-dbg libmpx2-dbg libquadmath0-dbg gdb-doc gdbserver gfortran-multilib gfortran-doc
  gfortran-8-multilib gfortran-8-doc libgfortran5-dbg libi2c-dev python-smbus iraf-dev apache2 | lighttpd | httpd
  libasound2-plugins alsa-utils libgssapi-perl liblapack-doc glibc-doc colord cups-common git bzr libfftw3-bin
  libfftw3-dev libgd-tools gphoto2 gvfs libhwloc-contrib-plugins icu-doc jackd2 liblcms2-utils libtool-doc
  libcrypt-ssleay-perl liblzma-doc ncurses-doc libmyodbc odbc-postgresql tdsodbc unixodbc-bin openmpi-doc opus-tools
  pcscd pulseaudio readline-doc librsvg2-bin hplip lm-sensors sndiod snmp-mibs-downloader libstdc++-8-doc
  libtk-img-doc gcj-jdk libauthen-ntlm-perl libunicode-map8-perl libunicode-string-perl xml-twig-tools m4-doc make-doc
  opencl-icd fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-wqy-microhei | fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-indic ed
  diffutils-doc libxml2-utils python-astropy-doc python3-astropy-affiliated python3-beautifulsoup python3-h5py
  python3-matplotlib python3-pandas python3-yaml python-attr-doc python-crypto-doc python-gevent-doc
  python-greenlet-doc python-greenlet-dev python-gssapi-doc python-jinja2-doc python-numpy-doc python3-numpy-dbg
  python-persistent-doc python-pexpect-doc python-pil-doc python3-pil-dbg python-ply-doc python-psutil-doc subversion
  python-pyaudio-doc python-pygments-doc ttf-bitstream-vera genisoimage ipython3 python-pyxattr-doc python-rpy-docs
  python3-sane-dbg python-scipy-doc tix python3-tk-dbg python-urwid-doc python-yenc-doc python3.7-venv python3.7-doc
  python3-gdbm-dbg binfmt-support ess r-doc-info | r-doc-pdf r-mathlib r-base-html texlive-base texlive-latex-base
  texlive-generic-recommended texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-extra texlive-extra-utils
  texlive-latex-recommended texlive-latex-extra texinfo mozilla | www-browser unpaper python3-pyds9 xpa-tools
  tcl-tclreadline tcllib-critcl mesa-utils nickle cairo-5c xorg-docs-core xfonts-cyrillic
Recommended packages:
  libgpm2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  acl adwaita-icon-theme at-spi2-core autoconf automake autotools-dev binutils binutils-common
  binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu blt build-essential bzip2-doc ca-certificates-java casacore-data casacore-data-igrf
  casacore-data-jpl-de200 casacore-data-jpl-de405 casacore-data-lines casacore-data-observatories
  casacore-data-sources casacore-data-tai-utc cpp cpp-8 cython3 dbus-user-session dconf-gsettings-backend
  dconf-service default-jre default-jre-headless dh-python dpkg-dev fakeroot fontconfig fontconfig-config
  fonts-dejavu-core fonts-dejavu-extra g++ g++-8 gcc gcc-8 gdb gfortran gfortran-8 glib-networking
  glib-networking-common glib-networking-services gsettings-desktop-schemas gtk-update-icon-cache hicolor-icon-theme
  i2c-tools ibverbs-providers icu-devtools iraf iraf-noao java-common javascript-common libaec0 libalgorithm-diff-perl
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libapr1 libaprutil1 libasan5 libasound2 libasound2-data
  libasyncns0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatomic1
  libatspi2.0-0 libauthen-sasl-perl libbabeltrace1 libbinutils libblas-dev libblas3 libbluetooth3
  libboost-python1.67.0 libbz2-dev libc-ares2 libc-dev-bin libc6-dbg libc6-dev libcaf-openmpi-3 libcairo-gobject2
  libcairo2 libcasa-casa3 libcasa-coordinates3 libcasa-fits3 libcasa-images3 libcasa-lattices3 libcasa-measures3
  libcasa-mirlib3 libcasa-ms3 libcasa-python3-3 libcasa-scimath-f3 libcasa-scimath3 libcasa-tables3 libcc1-0
  libcfitsio7 libcminpack1 libcoarrays-dev libcoarrays-openmpi-dev libcolord2 libcos4-2 libcroco3 libcups2
  libdata-dump-perl libdatrie1 libdconf1 libdpkg-perl libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-common libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2
  libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libdw1 libencode-locale-perl libepoxy0 liberfa1 libevent-2.1-6 libevent-core-2.1-6
  libevent-pthreads-2.1-6 libexif12 libexpat1-dev libfabric1 libfakeroot libfftw3-double3 libfftw3-single3
  libfile-basedir-perl libfile-desktopentry-perl libfile-fcntllock-perl libfile-listing-perl libfile-mimeinfo-perl
  libflac8 libfont-afm-perl libfontconfig1 libfontenc1 libfribidi0 libftdi1-2 libfuntools1 libgail-common libgail18
  libgcc-8-dev libgd3 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgfortran-8-dev libgfortran5
  libgif7 libgl1 libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libglvnd0 libglx-mesa0 libglx0 libgphoto2-6 libgphoto2-l10n
  libgphoto2-port12 libgraphite2-3 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common
  libharfbuzz0b libhdf5-openmpi-103 libhidapi-hidraw0 libhidapi-libusb0 libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl
  libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl
  libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libhwloc-dev libhwloc-plugins libhwloc5 libi2c0 libibverbs-dev
  libibverbs1 libice6 libicu-dev libieee1284-3 libimagequant0 libio-html-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl libio-stringy-perl
  libipc-system-simple-perl libipt2 libisl19 libitm1 libjack-jackd2-0 libjansson4 libjbig0 libjpeg-dev libjpeg62-turbo
  libjpeg62-turbo-dev libjs-jquery libjs-jquery-datatables libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-common
  libkyotocabinet16v5 liblapack-dev liblapack3 liblcms2-2 libldb1 libllvm7 liblog4tango5v5 liblsan0 libltdl-dev
  libltdl7 liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl liblzma-dev liblzo2-2 libmad0 libmailtools-perl
  libmariadb3 libmpc3 libmpfr6 libmpx2 libncurses-dev libncurses5-dev libnet-dbus-perl libnet-http-perl
  libnet-smtp-ssl-perl libnl-3-200 libnl-3-dev libnl-route-3-200 libnl-route-3-dev libnorm1 libnspr4 libnss3
  libnuma-dev libnuma1 libodbc1 libogg0 libomniorb4-2 libomnithread4 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenmpi-dev
  libopenmpi3 libopus0 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpaper-utils libpaper1 libpcap0.8
  libpciaccess0 libpcre16-3 libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libpcsclite1 libpgm-5.2-0 libpixman-1-0 libpmix2
  libpng-dev libpng-tools libportaudio2 libprelude23 libpreludecpp8 libproxy1v5 libpsm-infinipath1 libpsm2-2 libpulse0
  libpython3-dbg libpython3-dev libpython3.7 libpython3.7-dbg libpython3.7-dev libqrencode4 libquadmath0 librdmacm1
  libreadline-dev librest-0.7-0 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsamplerate0 libsane libsane-common libsensors-config
  libsensors5 libserf-1-1 libsfml-audio2.5 libsfml-graphics2.5 libsfml-network2.5 libsfml-system2.5 libsfml-window2.5
  libsigsegv2 libsiloh5-0 libsm6 libsmbclient libsndfile1 libsndio7.0 libsnmp-base libsnmp30 libsodium23
  libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libstarlink-ast-err0 libstarlink-ast0 libstarlink-pal0 libstdc++-8-dev libsvn1
  libsz2 libtalloc2 libtango9 libtcl8.6 libtdb1 libtevent0 libthai-data libthai0 libtie-ixhash-perl libtiff5
  libtimedate-perl libtk-img libtk8.6 libtool libtry-tiny-perl libtsan0 libubsan1 liburi-perl libutempter0
  libutf8proc2 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libvorbisfile3 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1
  libwbclient0 libwcs6 libwcstools1 libwebp6 libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux3 libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl
  libx11-protocol-perl libx11-xcb1 libx86-1 libxaw7 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0
  libxcb-render0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-sync1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxft2
  libxi6 libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxml-parser-perl libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpathengine-perl libxmu6 libxpa1
  libxpm4 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxshmfence1 libxslt1.1 libxss1 libxt6 libxtst6 libxv1 libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1
  libzmq5 linux-libc-dev m4 make manpages-dev mariadb-common mysql-common ocl-icd-libopencl1 openjdk-11-jre
  openjdk-11-jre-headless openmpi-bin openmpi-common patch pkg-config prelude-utils python-talloc python3-astropy
  python3-atomicwrites python3-attr python3-blist python3-bluez python3-btrees python3-cairo python3-cairo-dbg
  python3-casacore python3-crypto python3-crypto-dbg python3-cups python3-dbg python3-decorator python3-deltarpm
  python3-dev python3-ftdi1 python3-gevent python3-gevent-dbg python3-greenlet python3-greenlet-dbg python3-grpcio
  python3-gssapi python3-hid python3-http-parser python3-icu python3-icu-dbg python3-indexed-gzip python3-ipython
  python3-ipython-genutils python3-jinja2 python3-jpy python3-jpype python3-kdtree python3-kdtree-dbg
  python3-kyotocabinet python3-ldap python3-ldap-dbg python3-markupsafe python3-more-itertools python3-newt
  python3-nss python3-numpy python3-olefile python3-persistent python3-pexpect python3-pickleshare python3-pil
  python3-pluggy python3-ply python3-prelude python3-prompt-toolkit python3-psutil python3-ptyprocess python3-py
  python3-pyalsa python3-pyasn1 python3-pyasn1-modules python3-pyaudio python3-pygments python3-pyisomd5sum
  python3-pymad python3-pymad-dbg python3-pyodbc python3-pypcap python3-pyraf python3-pytest python3-pytest-arraydiff
  python3-pytest-astropy python3-pytest-doctestplus python3-pytest-openfiles python3-pytest-remotedata python3-pyxattr
  python3-pyxattr-dbg python3-qrencode python3-radix python3-rpy2 python3-sane python3-scipy python3-selinux
  python3-sendfile python3-sendfile-dbg python3-sfml python3-silo python3-simplegeneric python3-smbc python3-smbus
  python3-stsci.tools python3-subvertpy python3-tango python3-tk python3-traitlets python3-urwid python3-wcwidth
  python3-wheezy.template python3-yenc python3-zodbpickle python3.7-dbg python3.7-dev r-base-core r-base-dev
  r-cran-boot r-cran-class r-cran-cluster r-cran-codetools r-cran-foreign r-cran-kernsmooth r-cran-lattice r-cran-mass
  r-cran-matrix r-cran-mgcv r-cran-nlme r-cran-nnet r-cran-rpart r-cran-spatial r-cran-survival r-doc-html
  r-recommended read-edid samba-libs sane-utils saods9 saods9-doc tango-common tcl tcl-signal tcl-tls tcl-xpa tcl8.6
  tcliis tcllib tclxml tk tk-html1 tk-mpeg tk-table tk8.6 tk8.6-blt2.5 tkblt tkcon tksao unzip update-inetd x11-common
  x11-utils x11-xserver-utils xbitmaps xdg-utils xterm zip zlib1g-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bzip2 libbz2-1.0 libexpat1 libicu63 libncurses6 libncursesw6 libpython3.7-minimal libpython3.7-stdlib libtinfo6
  python3.7 python3.7-minimal
11 upgraded, 554 newly installed, 0 to remove and 74 not upgraded.
Need to get 477 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,676 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

To *only* install python 3.6 and its standard library, I would need 1600 MB. I find this extremely huge, especially since my system is 1.3 GB heavy and already has python 2.7 and 3.7 provided, and since the Windows .exe installer is only 25 MB.

I *could* install this as-is, but as I said, I try to take care about the storage space - plus, I'd want to do things in a clean way, and I guess a lot of packages in there are not really needed.

I guess apt probably provides me packages that I do not really need in a python installation: if it is the case, what do I need to do to remove them?
And if I cannot: is there a reason why installing python3.6 takes so much storage on a Debian?

Thank you!

Comment: "Note, selecting '...' for **regex 'python3.6'**. There is no `python3.6` package, so it's doing a regex match across package names. The python3 package is probably already 3.6.

Answer (score 4):

This is `apt` being overly helpful: if `apt install` fails to match the specified package, and the package contains `.`, `?`, or `*`, then it is interpreted as a regular expression, and any matching package is selected for installation. In your case, `python3.6` doesn’t exist, so `apt` proceeds to try to install a huge amount of related packages.

There’s no general way to install a specific version of Python using `apt`; you can only install one of the available versions (for Python 3 in Debian 10, that’s Python 3.7).

To work with specific versions of Python, you should use virtual environments instead of trying to install a system-wide Python package. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/577060/86440) for details.

(On Debian 10, a default Python installation on top of the base system occupies 36.3MB of disk space.)

Comment: So you mean we can install entire Python interpreters inside a virtualenv? I would be curious if you provided me a helpful link, as virtualenvs were always a mystery to use for me.